# How command line tool communicates with browser?

Tags: command-line, salesforce, command-line-interface, force.com

It is a command line tool [force-cli](https://force-cli.heroku.com)

When use `force login`, it opens browser and ask for Oauth login. After authorization, the browser closes and go back to command line tool.

I am new to command line tool (Terminal.app or cmd.exe)

My question is how command line tool communicates with browser. i.e. How `force login` command opens browser and how browser closes and go back to command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For opening browser from command line (cmd.exe in Windows or terminal in Linux-systems) you just need to know URL of page that you want to open and use some of appropriate command. For Windows command line it's `start` *`URL`*, for Linux - `firefox` *`URL`*, `x-www-browser` *`URL`* or some distributions have `xdg-open` *`URL`*, for MacOSX it is rumored to be `open` *`URL`*. For more information you can read [this article](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/open-files-urls.html).

Comment: For MacOSX it is rumored to be `open` *`URL`* and some Linux have `xdg-open` *`URL`* ...

Comment: Spelling: distributes -> distributions